# Dictionary from standard Android keyboard

Tags: android, dictionary, keyboard

Standard Android keyboard has dictionary for suggestion.
I need access to this dictionary.
How can I take this access?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to access it using the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.html provider interface: never actually seen the dictionary explicitly accessed by application code, so you may or may not succeed at that.

Comment: User Dictionary is another dictionary.
I need access to Standard dictionary.